# Почему тени отображаются неправильно?

Tags: three.js

Я отобразил модель и увеличил ее но 
Я не понимаю почему при увеличение у теней появляется ограничительная рамка
я проверял не near, far, radius, width, height, bias. на это не влияют

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто ни будь знает в чем причина?

Comment: Потому что еще нужно настроить камеру теней для источника света. Например, для DirectionalLight: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/lights/shadows/DirectionalLightShadow

Comment: А еще лучше добавить живой пример кода, который можно запустить и посмотреть, что и как там работает. (сниппет, jsfiddle, codepen)

Comment: @prisoner849 а я думал тут нету three.js эксперта...

Comment: @prisoner849 Я проверял но он не light.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;    
light.shadow.camera.far = 500; не влияют на это http://static2.keep4u.ru/2019/02/02/VAA9376f0c1a6fa2b61.gif

Comment: Для начала хорошо бы рассказать - какой тип источника света используется :) Потом попробовать поиграться с параметрами камеры теней: `light.shadow.mapSize.width` и `light.shadow.mapSize.height`, а если не помогает, то попробовать изменить параметры `top`, `left`, `bottom` и `right` все у того же объекта камеры теней.

Comment: Можно еще посмотреть про это вот в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663136/224917

Comment: @Избытоксусликов добро пожаловать на форум, если интересно: https://discourse.threejs.org :)

Comment: @prisoner849  Спасибо большое :)